# PyAudio (PortAudio issue) Python

Tags: python, anaconda, pyaudio, portaudio

I installed pyaudio with anaconda python. Using `conda install pyaudio` on windows.
It said it installed and it also installed `PortAudio` with it.

However, when I create my file and run it now I get the following issue.

I have no idea what is going on.

```
Could not import the PyAudio C module '_portaudio'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\This PC\Desktop\Py\demo.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pyaudio
  File "C:\Users\This PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyaudio.py", line 116, in <module>
    import _portaudio as pa
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this error with win32 py3 using Anaconda3. Re-installing portaudio fixed this:

```
conda install portaudio
```

It just updated the package for me, and pyaudio was able to find the DLL then.

Comment: This worked for me, followed ```pip install pyaudio```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue.

The only way I was able to resolve this was by uninstalling anaconda, installing the latest version of python, and reinstalling the latest version of conda.

I then downloaded the latest .whl file for pyaudio which can be found here: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio

I moved this file from my downloads and into the site-packages folder of anaconda3:
C:\Users\Projects\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages

Upon running the command 'pip install pyaudio' OR 'python -m pip install pyaudio' in the anaconda prompt I was good to go

I hope this helps!