# Portaudio import issue

Tags: python, pyaudio

I'm trying o run a simple audio program using pyaudio and wave, for that I'm using anaconda but i'm getting an error that has no solution on the net.

Already tried this
[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51998310/pyaudio-portaudio-issue-python)

```
Could not import the PyAudio C module '_portaudio'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Talha/Desktop/Python/aa.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyaudio
  File "C:\Users\Talha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyaudio.py", line 116, in <module>
    import _portaudio as pa
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

This is my code

```
import pyaudio
import wave
def play_audio(file):
    chunk = 1024
    wf=wave.open(file,'rb')
    pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = pa.open(
        format=pa.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
        channels= wf.getnchannels(),
        rate=wf.getframerate(),
        output=True
    )
    data_stream = wf.readframes(chunk)
    while data_stream:
        stream.write(data_stream)
        data_stream=wf.readframes(chunk)

    stream.close()
    pa.terminate()



play_audio('\sms.wav')
```

Comment: Did you install portaudio for windows? http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/tutorial_start.html

Comment: @Vishnudev as in for global level?

Comment: Yes. Pyaudio depends on the portaudio installation

Comment: @Vishnudev I tried installing it but it was giving a C library error, i found the solution to use Anaconda to avoid such dependencies errors. and now this

Comment: Just add bin of conda to your PATH

Comment: @Vishnudev No use

Answer (score 0):

As you found already, installing PyAudio with conda as opposed to pip covers some dependency issues

Try downgrading your python, PyAudio appears not to work on python 3.7+. I just had a similar error and fixed it by creating a python 3.6 virtual environment and running my same code there.